# Could I use a feat to augment my breath weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, breath-weapon

Could I use a feat to augment my breath weapon in any way, shape or form? If so, what feat(s)?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, any creature with a [breath weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Breath-Weapon-Su-) (which is a special attack) is eligible for the feat **[Ability Focus](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/ability-focus)**, which would add +2 to the save DC against their breath weapon. This feat is usually intended for monsters, so GM discretion applies if a player character wants this feat.

> Prerequisite: Special attack.
>
> Benefit: Choose one of the creature’s special attacks. Add +2 to the DC for all saving throws against the special attack on which the creature focuses.

There is another feat, **[Draconic Paragon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/draconic-paragon-kobold)**, but it has several prerequisites and is only available to kobolds with the [Draconic Breath](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/draconic-breath-kobold) racial feat (which gives them a breath weapon).  Draconic Paragon increases the damage and frequency of their breath weapon.

> Prerequisites: Draconic Aspect, Draconic Breath, Draconic Glide, character level 10th, kobold.
>
> Benefit: You gain an additional +2 bonus against sleep and paralysis effects. You can use your breath weapon twice per day and your breath weapon damage increases to 4d6 points of energy damage. Your wings from the Draconic Glide feat grow stronger, granting you a fly speed of 20 feet (average maneuverability).

There are no official Paizo feats that allow creatures to change the area of their breath weapons, although there are feats like [Shape Breath Weapon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/3rd-party-feats/frog-god-games/monster-feats-3pp-frog-god-games/shape-breath-weapon/) from 3rd party publishers.

Comment: *Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Bestiary* Appendix 5: Monster Feats notes that "Most of the following feats apply specifically to monsters, although some player characters might qualify for them (particularly Craft Construct)." If a PC has a special attack, then they qualify for Ability Focus, and a breath weapon feels like a special attack. (It is, if you go by monster statblocks, as defined in the glossary.)

Comment: @Powerdork Yes, my answer specifically says that breath weapons count as a special attack.

Comment: Mind the quote.

Comment: @Powerdork I saw the quote. Could you clarify what I am missing?